# Passing an array element by reference

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, mono, pass-by-reference

I am compiling the following code using `Mono compiler v4.2.1` (`.NET` Framework 4.5):

```
Module Module1
    Sub Change(ByRef x As Integer)
        x += 1
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim arr() As Integer = {1}
        Change(arr(0))
        Console.WriteLine(arr(0))
    End Sub
End Module
```

The produced output is: 1. Why doesn't the `x` parameter get bound to the array element by reference? Is there a way to make this work without having to pass the array?

**Additional details**:

- I am running the above code through [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment#!)
- The above code produces the output of 2 when run from Visual Studio 2010/2012.
- Not sure if motivation is important for the question, but passing an array element by reference is quite useful. For example, one can implement `Swap` that takes two array elements.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Mono VB compiler. The C# equivalent works fine (tested with Ideone, Mono 4.0.1)

Comment: yes please report bugs to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Excellent example of [mcve] - These kinds of questions are as rare as rocking horse droppings

Comment: Works as expected on Windows with VB.Net Visual Studio 2015, Framework 4.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Code is fine. Most definitely a bug in the compiler you are using.